# Hiding figcaption on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css

I'm in the process of updating my old website to a responsive design. I  cobble together bits of script to get the look I want, and definitely don't claim to fully understand it when it works, so I could use some simple-words advice. My original site used subcontent divs to show/hide captions. See here: http://www.nancychuang.com/projects/mtc/  for caption links below the images . For the new site, I purchased an inexpensive template and have been modifying it.

I didn't know how to apply the original caption into the new template, because the original was positioned using the extremely basic method of nested tables. It seems with this current template it's not possible to have text underneath the images, so I needed something unobtrusive on top. Was able to make figcaption script work by using the code from css-tricks SlideinCaptions.   So the new site will look like this: http://nancychuang.com/test/MTC.html .

```
    figure { 
display: block; 
position: relative; 
float: left; 
overflow: hidden; 
margin: 0 20px 20px 0; } 

    figcaption { 
position: absolute; 
    background: black; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75); 
    color: white; 
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    opacity: 0; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease; 
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease; } 

    figure:hover 
    figcaption { opacity: 1; } 

figure:before { 
    content: "?"; 
    position: absolute; 
    font-weight: 800; 
    background: black; 
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.75); 
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px white; 
    color: black; 
    width: 24px; height: 24px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 12px; 
    border-radius: 12px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size: 14px; 
    line-height: 24px; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease; 
    opacity: 0.75; } 

    figure:hover:before { opacity: 0; } 
    .cap-bot:before { bottom: 10px; left: 10px; } 
    .cap-bot figcaption { left: 0; bottom: -30%;} 
    .cap-bot:hover figcaption { bottom: 0; }
```

This figcaption script works on touch-screen, although to be honest I don't know why! There's no reference to touch or click in the code (so I can't figure out how to make the opposite action to "click off"). On desktop computer, hovering away from the image will hide the caption, on mobile the caption is stuck once activated. Since the text is proportionately large on mobile, I definitely want the user to be able to hide it. Either if there's a way to just touch anywhere on screen to make the caption disappear, OR like the original hidediv version where I add a link for the user to click:

```
<DIV id="subcontent1">
<p class="caption"><a href="http://maetaoclinic.org/" target="blank">Mae Tao Clinic</a>, started by Dr. Cynthia Maung in 1989, is the primary care facility for many Burmese living on the border. Helping refugees, uninsured migrant residents of Mae Sot, as well as Burmese who cross the border due to difficulties obtaining care on the other side, the clinic today offers a comprehensive range of services.

<p class="caption"><a class="caption" href="javascript:dropdowncontent.hidediv('subcontent1')">HIDE</a></p></td>
</DIV>
```

*related: with figcaption, can you specify the width of the hover block the way I did with my original subcontent divs? I'm not clear what 24px is referring to in the code...a minimum width, maybe? but no maximum?

Appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve exactly. Are you happy with the desktop version and only wants to change the mobile version? With CSS you can do a lot of things including have a completely different styling for the mobile version. For example you can have the caption always displayed on any position when on mobile, and so on. Let me know how you want it so maybe I can help.

Comment: Hi...so with this template it seems I cannot position the captions underneath the photos, and even if I could, some of them are quite long and would thus not fit. So for me, show/hide is a better option. I am happy with the desktop version, and am now seeing that I can actually "click off" the caption by touching the screen away from the photo on my Nook HD using Chrome, but NOT on iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw in an answer anyway...

In your CSS, you have:

```
figcaption { opacity: 0; }
```

which means that figcaption is not visible by default.

And you have:

```
figure:hover figcaption { opacity: 1; }
```

which means that the figcaption will be made visible when hovering the containing figure.

The above two styles are mainly what's causing the caption to appear on hovering the picture, and in the case of a mobile device - on tapping the picture.

You asked how to hide the caption on a mobile device once it appears. The simple answer is - based on the above CSS - to tap anywhere outside the picture which can be interpreted as the picture losing focus.

However, do you really want to have this effect on a mobile device? It is not very intuitive. There are ways to change the styling depending on device. For example, if viewed on mobile device, the figcaption should always appear underneath the picture, which makes more sense to me. This can be achieved by using media query CSS to target different screen sizes.

I suggest that you do some online CSS tutorials to learn all the cool things CSS can do. It's definitely worth the time especially that you're customising a website already.

Comment: So I answered a bit of your question above by talking about caption length, but I am not clear about "not intuitive" because I've only had a smartphone for a couple months, which is why I decided to redesign my site. Is show/hide by tapping really counter-intuitive? Is this a behavior that is now confusing to people? This is a genuine question, since I'm still learning my way w/ mobile. If it's really that odd, then I could consider doing it another way, but I definitely prefer the show/hide. Which is apparently only not working on iPhone, maybe not a problem on Android devices.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone so I can't see that it's not working. Android seems to be working by tapping on the photo to see the caption and tapping outside the photo to hide it. I'm not a user experience expert by any means. I just go by the rule of what feels right. The fact that you didn't know how to hide the caption once it appears on a mobile device is an indication that it's not user friendly. With this reason I suggested to keep it simple for mobile, with the caption always displayed. What you choose to do is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution you need to check is the device touch or not therefore CSS can define based on the result.

```
@media (-moz-touch-enabled: 0), (pointer: fine), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  figure:hover:before {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .cap-bot:before {
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  .cap-bot figcaption {
    left: 0;
    bottom: -30%;
  }
  .cap-bot:hover figcaption {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}
```